# What version of OpenGL Shading Language is equivalent to OpenGL ES 3.2 SL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader

What version of GLSL is equivalent to OpenGL ES 3.2 SL and do they have full parity or are there missing features? Is it safe to rely on an older version of The Orange book when learning to do ES shaders (primarily interested in Compute shaders)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no version of desktop GLSL that is exactly equivalent to ESSL 3.20. There are some features of GLSL that never made it into ES at all (shader subroutines, good riddance). And there are some features that, while technically part of both, only really matter in ESSL land (precision qualifiers, for example).

If you're not using ESSL-specific learning material, the best you can do is to reference the ESSL 3.20 specification when a new concept is introduced to make sure that it's available in ESSL.

Answer (score 1):

[Compute Shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader) are provided since [OpenGL 4.3](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec43.core.pdf), respectively [GpenGL Shading Language 4.30](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.30.pdf).
They are also available by the extension [ARB_compute_shader](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_compute_shader.txt).

Comment: mid last year chrome made a switch to turn on compute shader. #version 310 es

Comment: @nabr The question is not about OpenGL ES. It is about desktop OpenGL. No one made a switch (OpenGL is a specification). Compute shaders are supproted since OpenGL ES 3.1. Compare [Khronos OpenGL® Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) and [Khronos OpenGL ES Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php)

Answer (score 1):

"What version of GLSL is equivalent to OpenGL ES 3.2 SL"

- https://github.com/9ballsyndrome/WebGL_Compute_shader

"do they have full parity or are there missing features"

- read the spec, likely the second.

"safe to rely on an older version of The Orange book"

- you need that specific explorer personality, turning failure into successful experience and a lot of time. Whatever tutorials comes on the first three pages as websearch results, - i would call "safe".